# Does donating to Saint Esselin do anything?

Tags: momodora-reverie-under-moonlight

In *Momodora: Reverie Under the Moonlight*, I came across a lady in the Forlorn Monastery who told me I could achieve salvation by donating to Saint Esselin. I said yes and donated 15 munnies, but nothing seemed to change. Talking to her again after donating just repeated the same dialogue and prompt to donate.

Does donating to Saint Esselin do anything?

[image: Woman asking for donations]

[image: Map location]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to obtain from making donations to this lady. Even if you kept donating anything to her, you will never be rewarded with anything in particular.